# group_by() and unique() in R both return a duplicate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I have a list of samples. Each sample has a country of origin. There is a column that is country.

I run the following code:

```
country_counts <- metadata %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  count()
```

For 192 countries, this works. Romania, however, is duplicated. I have done everything I know to fix this. I have removed the white spaces, I have used str_replace. Still I am left with the duplicate. When I use str_replace and replace with "apple", I am left with two "apple" variables. I am not sure what left to do. I have also tried copying the column and copying the entire database. Still nothing works for me. Any advice?

Comment: please show a reproducible example. using `dput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there is some issue with character in the string. Looks the same but is a different unicode character.
My quick and dirty solution would be to use `str_detect` to replace all Romania-like strings.

```
metadata$country[str_detect(metadata$country, "Ro")] <- "Romania"
```

You have to adjust the pattern in `str_detect` to make it work in your specific case.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. I thought replacing the entire string did the same, but apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: It seems as if your data includes strings that look like "Romania" but in terms of unicode are something else.
Could you please accep the answer so that the question is marked as "answered"?